# Carpal Singapore - Pickup time is less than 30 minutes from now (8)

Tags: php, curl

I used below code to generate pickup_time .

```
// For Date
    $dt = date('d-m-Y');

    // For Time
    $tm = date('H:i');
    $timestamp = strtotime($tm) + 60*60;

    $time = date('H:i', $timestamp);
```

I used it like below to send the curl request

```
'pickup_date' => $dt,
'pickup_timing' => $time,
```

But I got the Response

> Pickup time is less than 30 minutes from now (8)

I don't know why?

Singapore is the country for which I'm developing the code.

Comment: check what the default timezone is, could be that.

Comment: For which country , you are performing the task .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a server send request to other server , they used their own timezone in default. That's why time make difference in requested code and error generated

For Singapore , try this :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');
```

Answer (score 1):

Php depends upon time zone

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Singapore");
echo "The Singapore time is after 30 Mintues from now " . date("h:i", time() + 3600);
```